# Stop connection message coming back for Connect-VIServer

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have an IIS machine hosting some PHP that calls a Powershell file. After adding the Powercli snap in in my Powershell file, I makes a connection to vSphere.

When it does it produces some output that I don't want as this gets put on to each php output page.

Name Port User ---- ---- ---- myhostaddress.com 443 mynetwork\reporteruser

I have tried to add variables to the end to stop the feedback

```
Connect-VIServer -server myhostaddress.com -User $logincred.User -Password $logincred.Password  -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction Continue
```

but no use.

Is there a way to stop it. Or a clever way to call it so the output is dumped somewhere else please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign the connection to a variable to suppress the output:

```
$connection = Connect-VIServer -Server myhostaddress.com  -Credential $cred
```

Working on PS v5.

Answer (score 1):

before executing, run the following code:

```
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null):

```
Connect-VIServer -Server ... | Out-Null
```

This is the PowerShell equivalent of redirecting `stdout` to `/dev/null` in Linux (`... > /dev/null`).